# RxJs consequent observables: continue execution if an error occurs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need to combine two api calls - `serviceA` and `serviceB`. `serviceB` should be called right after `serviceA`. However, if `serviceA` fails, the code should continue execution and call `serviceB`.

What's the right way to do it, using RxJS?

Here's what I've tried:

```
this.serviceA.getData(id).pipe(
    map((data) => {
      return { ...data, test: "abc" };
    }),
    mergeMap((res) => {
      return this.serviceB.getData(id).pipe(
        map((scores) => this.handleData(scores)),
        catchError(() => of(res))
      );
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `catchError` earlier in the pipe if you want to catch errors from service A:

```
this.serviceA.getData().pipe(
    catchError(errA => of(errA)),
    map(dataA => ({ ...dataA, test: "abc" })),
    switchMap(objA => this.serviceB.getData(objA)),
    catchError(errB => of(errB)),
    map(dataB => this.handleData(dataB))
);
```

In the above code, the first `catchError` will catch errors that occurred in the call to `serviceA.getData()` and return an observable the `switchMap` will receive as `dataA`.  Execution will continue, so serviceB gets called regardless of whether or not an error has occurred.

The second `catchError` will catch errors from `serviceB.getData()`.

This interactive [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66646946?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demonstrates this behavior.